# Get MusicSequence callback from MIDI Playback

Tags: ios, midi, audio-player

I currently have a [MusicPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicPlayerServices_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009301) which contains a [MusicSequence](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicSequence_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MusicSequenceSetUserCallback) with a set of [MusicTracks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicTrack_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009332) that hold MIDI information. What I want is to know when a MIDI Note starts reproducing and when it ends, something like a listener of the playback of the MIDI.

I was looking and think of maybe using [MusicSequenceSetUserCallback](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicSequence_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MusicSequenceSetUserCallback) but I don't really know how would that work. Anybody has an idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this help?: http://www.deluge.co/?q=midi-driven-animation-core-audio-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a tutorial on how to capture midi events from a `MusicSequence` here (such as note on/off): http://www.deluge.co/?q=midi-driven-animation-core-audio-objective-c

In brief, the method is to call `MIDIDestinationCreate` to create your own MIDI endpoint to handle the MIDI messages, and then point your `MusicSequence` at it with `MusicSequenceSetMIDIEndpoint`.

Comment: Any idea on how to capture timestamp and track information from that callback?

Comment: @patchdiaz I don't have a definitive answer for either of those, I'm afraid--I've never done it myself. You could maybe just try calling `MusicPlayerGetTime` when the messages come in to get the timestamp (although not sure if that's the most accurate method). And possibly if you're playing each of the tracks through an individual sampler you could read the track from that?